# Windows + Python + SQLite3 - near "ORDER": syntax error

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 with Python and Windows10. I wrote the following code.

```
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('''
    DELETE FROM stack ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1;
''')
```

And I execute that code on Bash on Ubuntu (WSL). That is succeeded.
But I got a error message "syntax error" on runnning on cmd.exe (not WSL).

```
>python stack.py
near "ORDER": syntax error
```

My wrote code is illegal on Windows? 
Python version is 3.7.0 on cmd.exe, and 3.5.2 on Bash.

Comment: Was your version of the sqlite library created and compiled using the option to allow `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` with `DELETE`? It's not enabled by default

Comment: Not in memory. I think maybe it has not been activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html), `DELETE` only accepts `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` if the [SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) option is set when, not only compiling the [sqlite3.c amalgamation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) file, but also when creating it from the master source. This is not done by default; it has to be specially turned on.

So to use it, you'd have to [download](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) sqlite-src-XXXXXX.zip (Near the bottom of the page), use that to create the sqlite3.c file (On unixish environments, you'd run `./configure` with the `--enable-update-limit` option; not sure how to to turn it on using the MSVC build instructions as I've never used them), and run make. That'll produce sqlite3 libraries that have it enabled. Then you have to make Python use them (Also something I don't know how to do; I'm pretty sure there's other questions here on that topic that have answers you can look up).

Basically, unless you're working on something written in C or C++ and can just include sqlite3.c directly in your project instead of using a library version, using any of the optional features in sqlite is a pain in the rear and I get the impression most people don't bother.